# Convert the following VB code to a LINQ statement?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I only want to return a certain number of rows into the DataTable via LINQ's Take or use it on the Rows property, but I am not sure how or where to do it:  Here is the current code:

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = GetDataTable("sp", params)
 For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim o As New OR()
        o.P = p
        o.Id = dr ("A")
        o.R = dr ("B")
 Next
```

Would it be something like:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = GetDataTable("sp", params).AsEnumerable().Take(10)
```

When I run the above, I get the error:

`The 'TakeIterator' start tag on line 4 position 60 does not match the end tag of 'Error'. Line 4, position 137.`

`Unable to cast object of type '<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[System.Data.DataRow]' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.`

Comment: yes, it is `AsEnumerable().Take(10)`

Comment: You're creating instances of type `OR` in the loop. Do you want to add them to a `List(Of Or)`? What do you want to return, a `DataTable`, an `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)` or a `List(Of Or)`? How is it related to LINQ-To-Sql?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I know, it was just some quick code I pasted, it is not the exact code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I just wanted to know if I could utilize Take()

Comment: Technically, your VB code does nothing (unless creating a `OR` object had side-effects which would be a bad idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a `DataTable`:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = (From row in GetDataTable("sp", params) Take 10).CopyToDataTable()
```

If you need a `List(Of [Or])` (you need the brackets since `Or` is a keyword)

```
Dim list As List(Of [Or]) = (From row In GetDataTable("sp", params)
                            Select New [Or]() {
                                o.Id = row.Field(Of Int32)("Id"),
                                o.R =  row.Field(Of String)("R")
                            }).Take(10).ToList()
```

**Edit**:

> is there a way I can also include a Where with the Take, for example, I have 3 statuses in my table, Open, Semi-Open, Closed, I only want to Take 10 for Open, but I want to leave Semi-Open and Closed alone. As an example Semi-Open and Closed will have 5 records combined and I will take 10 from Open, so I would get a total of 15 rows

Yes, there's a way:

```
Dim dt =  GetDataTable("sp", params)
Dim open10 = From row In dt
             Where row.Field(Of String)("Status") = "Open"
             Take 10
Dim rest = From row In dt
           Where row.Field(Of String)("Status") <> "Open"
Dim tblResult = open10.Concat(rest).CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: Ah, this probably explains my error I received, I did not put CopyToDataTable

Comment: Can I do it on dt.Rows or is it better to do it on the the returned DataTable? I am assuming if I do it on the DataTable, it will be faster in pulling all the data, correct?

Comment: Just curious, why do I need to do CopyToDataTable?

Comment: @Xaisoft: You need `CopyToDataTable` to create a new DataTable since `DataTable.AsEnumerable` returns an enumerator on the original DataRow collection. LINQ is a query language, if you want to materialize the result you need to copy it into a new object(f.e. via `ToList,ToArray or CopyToDataTable`). But only if you need to persist the result, you can even use the `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)` without copying it into a new DataTable.

Comment: is there a way I can also include a Where with the Take, for example, I have 3 statuses in my table, Open, Semi-Open, Closed, I only want to Take 10 for Open, but I want to leave Semi-Open and Closed alone. As an example Semi-Open and Closed will have 5 records combined and I will take 10 from Open, so I would get a total of 15 rows